# Default Selection in dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have the following code that generates a dynamic dropdown from information in a database table.  I want to have a default selection, so that if the user forgets to choose an option, an error is generated. Something like: `"-------"`,  `"       "`, `" ________"`

```
<li>Course Code: 
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT course_code, course_title, course_unit
                       FROM courses") or die(mysql_error());

echo '<select name="course_code">';
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<option value="'.$row1['course_code'].'">'.$row1['course_code'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
</li><br />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add code like this:

```
echo "<option value='' selected='selected'></option>";
```

right after this line:

```
echo'<select name = "course_code">';
```

NOTE: The property `selected='selected'` will make sure that it is the selected value on first run.

Comment: I would propose `echo "<option value=''>-- Please select an option --</option>";` so they can check for `$course_code == ''` to determine if it was not selected, instead of having to check if the value is `------------` to determine if it is blank.

Comment: @drew010 proposal accepted. You are right, empty value would be a better value.